# php zip extract makes file empty

Tags: php, web, zip, backend, archive

Ok so this is making me crazy... I abstracted the code because it comes from a big project. But in my project I ended up commenting everything and only have this left which is still causing problems and I have no idea why.

```
$f = fopen('tmp/'.$name.'.zip', 'wb');
fwrite($f, $myzip);
fclose($f); //I can open this file manually and everything is fine
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('tmp/'.$name.'.zip'); //$res is "1"
$zip->extractTo("final/" . $unique);
$zip->close();
```

As you can see I write a zip file in `/tmp`, at this point, I can open the file manually and it contains all files with the correct size.
But after I extract it to `/final`, for some reason some files are empty...
Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Did you check the file contents after creating the zip file, before extract it? Did it contain all the files as desired?

Comment: Yes, it's only after extracting it that extracted files are empty

Comment: Can you try extracting to a static path: `$zip->extractTo("/final/myPath/");`. And do you see any pattern (i.e. - file extension) in the files that are empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way by throwing Exception at zip archive open time,

```
function DecompressFile()
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('tmp/'.$name.'.zip') === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo("final/" . $hwidDir);
        $zip->close();
        return 'completed';
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception ("Decompress operation from ZIP file failed.");
    }
}
```